# ASP.NET MVC Custom Membership Guide

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, roleprovider

I am trying to make the move from PHP to ASP.NET. I have about 10 years experience with PHP, and 4 with C#.
But I having problems with the authentication and membership system in ASP.NET. So i have spend quit a lot of time finding a guide on how to create a membership provider for a custom database setup from scratch, but i can't find any that i can get to work.

So do one of you guys know a good guide to creating and implementing a custom membership provider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a ton of great ASP.NET Security related tutorials and information at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/security.

Specifically on how to create a custom MembershipProvder: http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider.

You can also read this: [Using Access instead of SQL server for your ASP.NET Application Services](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingAccessInsteadOfSQLServerForYourASPNETApplicationServices.aspx) which has a download to sample providers.

Answer (score -1):

Creating a custom membership provider is usually as simple as creating a class that inherits SqlMembershipProvider and then setting it up in the web.config